# How To Call @printf in LLVM through the module builder system

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am learning LLVM. I understand that thre are a number of useful C functions that are provided in LLVM already as intrinsic. So I'm trying to call the @printf function from my code.

I found the respective parts in the LLVM reference manual that describe the IR code to do that, which is relative clear:

```
declare i32 @printf(i8* noalias nocapture, ...)
call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* %msg, i32 12, i8 42)
```

etc. But I am not able to find how to do that using the IRBuilder<> class. I checked the builder class but I wasn't able to figure anything out.

I don't want to pass any fancy variables, basically just something like

```
printf( "%lu", variable_64_bit );
```

in C or something like that.

Could anybody give me an idea what I must do to call the printf function through the builder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean the `IRBuilder`?

Comment: Yes sorry, I correct my questions regarding this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found an [answer to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168815/adding-a-function-call-in-my-ir-code-in-llvm) elsewhere. In fact it goes somewhat beyond my original question but it was helpful for me and hopefully it will help somebody else as well.

Answer (score 4):

```cpp
    void kprintf(Module *mod, BasicBlock *bb, const char *format, ...)
    {
        Function *func_printf = mod->getFunction("printf");
        if (!func_printf) {
            PointerType *Pty = PointerType::get(IntegerType::get(mod->getContext(), 8), 0);
            FunctionType *FuncTy9 = FunctionType::get(IntegerType::get(mod->getContext(), 32), true);

            func_printf = Function::Create(FuncTy9, GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, "printf", mod);
            func_printf->setCallingConv(CallingConv::C);

            AttrListPtr func_printf_PAL;
            func_printf->setAttributes(func_printf_PAL);
        }

        IRBuilder <> builder(mod->getContext());
        builder.SetInsertPoint(bb);

        Value *str = builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(format);
        std::vector <Value *> int32_call_params;
        int32_call_params.push_back(str);

        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, format);

        char *str_ptr = va_arg(ap, char*);
        Value *format_ptr = builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(str_ptr);
        int32_call_params.push_back(format_ptr);

        std::vector<llvm::Value*> extra;
        do {
            llvm::Value *op = va_arg(ap, llvm::Value*);
            if (op) {
                int32_call_params.push_back(op);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } while (1);
        va_end(ap);

        CallInst * int32_call = CallInst::Create(func_printf, int32_call_params, "call", bb);
    }
    #define oprintf(...) kprintf(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define llvm_printf(...) oprintf(mod, bb, __VA_ARGS__, NULL)

    llvm_printf("Output: 0x%08X %f %d\n", 0x12345678, 3.1415926, 12345);
```

Hope to be of help to you